# Why do we have $i^2 = -1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I wonder what is the connection between the square root of negative numbers and the complex plane.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer depends on what construction of $\mathbf C$ you know.

Comment: @Bernard you already lost me, I just know one, I guess.

Comment: In the complex plane, the points on the vertical axis are marked as $i, 2i, 3i, 4i...$. To plot the complex number $2+3i$ you just plot the point $(2, 3)$ as you would on a normal set of axes.

Comment: Sure, but which it? Pairs of real numbers with addition componentwise and a specific multiplication?

Comment: @Bernard yup, the most basic one.

Comment: @Ovi: this is not a construction of $\mathbf C$ in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @Ovi  my concern is not how to represent them, I am interested if it's corelated to rotating points around the origin.

Comment: @DimitrieMititelu Yes, it is. To multiply two complex numbers, you multiply their lengths and add their angles. For example $i$ has length $1$ and angle $90$ degrees. Therefore $i \cdot i$ has length $1 \cdot 1 = 1$ and angle $90+90=180$, and the number with length $1$ and angle $180$ degrees is indeed $-1$.

Comment: @DimitrieMititelu I imagine that the question of complex multiplication corresponding to rotation/scaling has been asked many times here. Did you look into this? [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/computing-a-rotation-complex-numbers-vs-rotation-matrix) is a place to start

Comment: @AndresMejia Yes, i don't worry about the multiplication, i don't understand how from roots of negative numbers we put the same i on the complex plane. what is the reason for it?

Comment: @GunnarSveinsson Thanks! not sure what i was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the construction of $\mathbf C$ as the set $\mathbf R\times\mathbf R$, endowed with an addition and a multiplication defined as follows:
\begin{cases}\begin{aligned}
(a,b)+(a',b')&=(a+a',b+b'),\\
(a,b)(a',b')&=(aa'-bb',ab'+a'b),
\end{aligned}\end{cases}
one proves that $\mathbf C$ is a field and identify the real numbers  as a subfield of $\mathbf C$ via the field homomorphism
$\begin{aligned}[t]
i:\mathbf R&\longrightarrow\mathbf C \\
x&\longmapsto (x,0)
\end{aligned} $
This $i(1)=(1,0)$. Now by construction, $\mathbf C$ is an $\mathbf R$-vector space of dimension $2$, and its canonical basis is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. Every element is $\mathbf C$ can indeed be written as $\;(x,y)=x(1,0)+y(0,1)$.

One identifies $(1,0)$ with the real number $1$ (it is indeed the unit element for the multiplication in $\mathbf C$), and the  element $(0,1)$ is denoted $i$. It is easily checked that
$$(0,1)(0,1)=(-1,0),$$
and with the above conventions/denotations, this can be written as  $\;i^2=-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bernard ! I don't know why i supposed it's the other way around.

Comment: Indeed, any multiplication $(a,b)(a',b'):=(aa'+αbb',ab'+a'b+βbb')$, provided that $\beta^2+4\alpha \lneq 0$, gives rise to a field $\mathbb{C}'(\alpha,\beta)$ which isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}'(-1,0)$.